# Data stale when returning to previously loaded page. (Prisma)

Tags: next.js, prisma, vercel

I have a list of my products in card format.  You can click on a card to go to an edit screen.  within the edit screen you can modify or delete the product. After either you will be returned to the products list.

When you return to that list any data that has changed is not reflected unless I hard reload that window.

How do I get it to repull data after the router.push()

The data is being pulled like this:

```
async function getProds() {
  const products: Product[] = await prisma.product.findMany()
  return products
}

async function Products({}: Props) {

  const products = await getProds() // prisma.product.findMany()

...
```

I have both of these on the page to try to disable caching:

```
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'
export const revalidate = 0
```

So far nothing has gotten it to refresh, unless I click reload.  Consequently, if I go back to edit the product a second time its the old version of the data until I refresh.

Any Ideas? This is a new framework for me, I'm used to Rails still :)

Comment: `router.push()` does a client side routing. Call `router.refresh()` just below the line, and you should be fine normally.